# Ms Access Date function not passing in LIKE query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to query records from the access database that matches the current date (system date)

The following query works fine if I enter the date literally.

```
SELECT SUBJECT, TYPE, CH_NO, TEST_NAME, TEST_CODE, SDATE, ID
FROM MCQS_PAPER
WHERE [SDATE] ALIKE "%5/14/2022%"
```

I have added the `Date()` function in the criteria to avoid manual work, but it's not returning any records.

```
SELECT SUBJECT, TYPE, CH_NO, TEST_NAME, TEST_CODE, SDATE, ID
FROM MCQS_PAPER
WHERE [SDATE] ALIKE "% Date() %"
```

Why does the date function not work?

Comment: What is the datatype of sdate column

Comment: Its `Date/Time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing a date/time value with a string is wrong. You can test a date/time value (e.g. `05/14/2022 11:15 AM`) against current date (e.g. `05/14/2022`) like so:

```
WHERE [SDATE] >= Date()
AND   [SDATE] < DateAdd("d", 1, Date())
```

Comment: Wow... That's awesome :-)